# Refresh on JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having problems with my app.

Basically is won't load the latest code until to page is refreshed.

You go from page A to B but the app won't load the page properly until I either refresh or reload the app or change the link to external, which I don't want to do because it will open the browser and a new page.

Does anyone know how to sort these issue out or have any ideas please?

Comment: please show us a link a paste rather here the code you use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have visited a page before it will be cached by jQuery Mobile and next time you try to access it it won't contact the server.  [This](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/add-an-attribute-to-prevent-particular-pages-from-caching) might help you remove caching on some or all pages.